# How do I make a dot animation in a label widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to animate three dots in a label widget but I have no clue how.

My code so far:

```
def destroyy1():
    button2.destroy()
    running1 = Label(root, text="Running...", font="Arial, 12", bg="light green")
    running1.place(x=102, y=70)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the Label widget provided by tkinter. Then you need `after` method to update the text at regular interval and a `count` variable that keeps track of the number of `'.'`(dots). you might also have to store the actual text in another variable as shown below

```py
import tkinter as tk

def fun():
    global count
    lbl.config(text=text+'.'*count)

    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        count=0

    root.after(1000, fun)


root = tk.Tk()

count = 0
text='Running'

lbl = tk.Label(root, text=text, font="Arial, 12", bg="light green")
lbl.place(x=102, y=70)
fun()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn`t really work as I wished. Instead of animating the dots in the existing window it opens a new one instead and then gave me a error.

Comment: @antique what error? I can't help you if you don't provide your complete code.

Comment: Oh, I figured out why. Thanks for help!

Comment: Nice approach, I would have made a transition list like `[running, running., running.., running...]` and then index through it, this seems better.